# Ubuntu 16.04 nvidia-prime not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus

On Ubuntu 16.04 , installed nvidia drivers (nvidia-367) , I got the below error while launching `nvidia-setting` :-

```
ERROR: Error querying target relations

** Message: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? no

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should
   have been installed along with this driver at either
   /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-367.18-key-documentation
   or /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
   application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
   preopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
   Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.
```

Could anyone please help me with this issue.

Comment: I got a similar message, in my case I cannot use the NVIDIA driver when I attach my second monitor to the display port. As soon as I do that, the UI changes, I think Unity fails to load, and the monitor is not recognized. I'm on a Dell 7510 with the Quadro M1000M GPU. If I unplug the secondary monitor an reboot, my Unity is back again.

Comment: I'm having the same issue after installing the nvidia-375 driver for the GTX 1060. Does anyone have a solution to this?